# How to build an android project the same way eclipse does

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, adt

I have an android project in eclipse and I like to build the project occasionally with ant. However I want to build it the exact same way as eclipse does. When I build it with eclipse the results in bin/ differ from when I build it with `ant release` or `ant debug`, so obviously eclipse is not running plain `ant release` or `ant debug`.

What command line is eclipse running and how to find it out?

Comment: There is nothing you can do. That is the main reason, why google started the android-studio project.

Comment: eclipse uses "JDTCompilerAdapter" not "javac" compiler to build